# How to create an array of object with 2 arrays .js

Tags: javascript

I have two arrays

```
study_id: ["1", "2", "3"],
study_name: ["clinic Study", "study test", "test 2"],
```

I want to create an array of objects with the array as follows:

```
  "studies": [{
      "study_id": "1",
      "study_name": "clinic study"
    },
    {
      "study_id": "2",
      "study_name": "test study"
    }
  ]
```

How to achieve this?
thanks

Comment: you need to be sure that the order of both arrays if correct though, it's prone to errors

Answer (score -1):

there are a few ways to do this but one ES6 solution is to use map method in first array and map each element to a object which key is element from first array and value is element with same index in the second array.

```js
var a = [1, 2, 3]
var b = ['a', 'b', 'c']

var c = a.map((e, i) => {
  return { [e]: b[i] };
});

console.log(c)
```

Comment: There is no ES6 specific feature in the code.